# How to force a directory listing using SimpleHTTPServer?

Tags: javascript, python

I have an `index.html` on the folder where SimpleHTTPServer is running, but depending on the value of a URL GET parameter I want to show a directory listing instead. Is that possible? I was trying to query the root directory using ajax, but it returns `index.html`by default.

I guess one possible option is to rename `index.html` to something like `main.html` and never use index.html.

Comment: Is it this SimpleHTTPServer? http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: If renaming index.html is an option, it's by far the easiest solution. In fact, it's probably a good starting point even if you still need to adjust the behavior for certain GET parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override do_GET() and catch the path and parameter you are interested in, and do the right thing from there.

Comment: I think I might do that. Do you know where the file is stored?